# Where shall we six meet again?

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

1.

> In an Italian Swiss city,I am the head
>
> Of a bride locked in a box until she was dead

2.

> from Orange in France,we are dry,dry,dry
>
> We three are a bittersweet mix-hi!hi!hi!

3.

> Quite disturbed,I ended up in a California city
>
> Where little champions sang how I was so pretty

4.

> I ended up in the same place,but started in a really high state,
>
> I am the soft one amongst all of my mates.

5.

> At the head of a Cuban dance,preceded by a headless flight,
>
> You'll see me when Dawn appears,for I am silver and white.

6.

> I'm hiding!Just a second-I've no idea! Okay,Hallo! Can you see?
>
> Sounds like I'm the spirit of the tuba-that's me!

---

Anywhere else with us, you'll be cooled down quick

But here specifically, you'll find an extra kick.

Identify us all and find out what-and-where we all come together.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Partial answer, could it be?:

> A Long Island Iced Tea?

Clue #1

> GIN. Legend of the missing bride, Ginevra. Ginevra is also the Italian name for Geneva.

Clue #2

> TRIPLE SEC. "dry dry dry", orange flavoured alcohol from France

Clue #3

> TEQUILA. Also a 1958 song by The Champs.

Clue #4

> COLA. High state could be referring to carbonation. And the only non-alcoholic 'soft' one among other liquors

Clue #5

> RUM. As suggested by @Gareth

Clue #6

> VODKA. Transparent, looks like water, so can 'hide' easily

"Anywhere else with us, you'll be cooled down quick

But here specifically, you'll find an extra kick.

Identify us all and find out what-and-where we all come together"

> If you replace Long Island, (anywhere else), its just an iced tea, cools you down, but here you get an 'extra kick' from alcohol.

Comment: "High state" almost certainly refers to Colorado which has lots of very high mountains. It is the state with the [largest mean elevation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_by_elevation).

Comment: The vodka hides in the second letters of each word in "I've no idea! Okay,Hallo!"

Comment: Woah, nice catch!

Comment: The headless flight is quite literal: Long Island Ice Tea is made with light rum. And about the vodka again: It is made from potatoes or tubers, which sounds like tuba.

Comment: To be more specific, I bet #4 parses as CO/LA; as well as ending -LA, presumably there's some relevant song mentioning tequila.

Comment: There is a 1958 song named "Tequila" by a band named "The Champs". You're right, since it ends in 'LA'

Answer (score 5):

Well, #2 must surely be a reference to

> triple sec liqueur ("dry, dry, dry"; made with oranges).

This suggests that the whole thing may be pointing at a

> cocktail,

in which case perhaps #5 might be

> rum (which begins RUMBA, a Cuban dance); presumably the rest of the clue indicates that preceding it with "a headless flight" (perhaps a word meaning "flight" with its first letter removed) yields something associated with dawn, silver and white. I haven't figured out what yet, but there are quite a lot of -RUM words and e.g. ELECTRUM and SPECTRUM seem like they're in the right ballpark.

Unfortunately my ignorance of

> alcoholic drinks

is pretty much boundless, and if the guesses above are right I'm now more or less stuck :-).

Comment: "_something associated with dawn, [silver and white](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rum#Grades)_"

Comment: & 3 is ROT13 grdhvyn.

Answer (score 1):

Well quarkle got all of them except for #5 which Gareth chipped in and #6 which M Oehm managed. Other folks managed to add in bits and bobs as necessary.

Just to tie up a few loose ends

> #1-Gin (from the Italian for Geneva and the lovely legend of Ginevra)
>  #2-triple sec is made from bitter and sweet oranges
>  #3-anagram of Quite and then LA
>  #4-CO for Colorado(the high state in terms of elevation.... but also now they've legalized weed...)
>  #5-RUM from Rumba and light--headless flight
>  #6-Vodka is hidden in the alternating letters(from just a second) :)